# How to filter rows exactly matched date range?

Tags: mysql

```sql
SELECT 
DISTINCT 
    r.hotel_id, 
    rs.availableDate  
FROM rooms r
INNER JOIN
(SELECT 
    room_id, 
    JSON_ARRAYAGG(date) availableDate 
    FROM room_status rs
    WHERE `date` 
    BETWEEN "2023-03-08" AND "2023-03-13" AND is_available = true
    GROUP BY rs.room_id) AS rs
ON r.id = rs.room_id;
```

above is my sql statements.

My output is

[image: my sql rows output]

I want to get rows matched exactly in range "2023-03-08" AND "2023-03-13".

But I got others exactly not matched. In picture, it's hotel_id is 1,2,3

Comment: Can you add some simple data from both tables and tables definitions

Comment: In attached picture, dates are only in the range of "2023-03-08" AND "2023-03-13". What extra rows you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Try This , i think it'll help.

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.hotel_id, rs.availableDate  
  FROM rooms r
 INNER JOIN room_status rs on r.id = rs.room_id
 WHERE rs.availableDate >= "2023-03-08" 
   AND rs.availableDate <= "2023-03-13" 
   AND rs.is_available = true
 GROUP BY rs.room_id
```